# How to get Collection1 in Bitnami Solr

Tags: apache, solr, bitnami

I have installed Bitnami Apache Solr Stack 5.0.0-0 in MS-Windows 7 Professional Service Pack 1. I was trying to learn it and tried to follow http://wern-ancheta.com/blog/2013/06/15/getting-started-with-solr/. 
Things are bit interesting. Solr Admin functions are fine, but I am not finding the following aspects. 
I am not finding schema.xml in the given path-it is in some other path. 
I am finding apache-solr\exampledocs but not being able to do post.sh *.xml. 
I am not finding "solr\collection1" in the command prompt nor in the console. 
And any suggestion for any good tutorial? I searched internet but did not get much.